# add_regressor automatically for df w/ unknown amount of cols after y?

Tags: r, facebook-prophet

I have am generating a df with ds and y, but 0 to many columns that I want to use as regressors with Prophet. Is there any way I can automate adding regressors to the model for all the cols of a df through Prophet instead of hardcoding this?

i.e.- for the below; can I add the regressors for all the cols in a df in an automated way?

```
library(prophet)
df = data.frame('ds' = seq(as.Date('2019-07-01'), as.Date('2019-07-31'), by='day'),
                'y' = c(1:31),
                'x1' = jitter(c(31:61), factor=3, amount = NULL),
                'x2'= seq(0,4*pi,,31))

prophet_fit <- prophet() %>% 
  add_regressor('x1') %>% 
  add_regressor('x2') %>% 
  fit.prophet(df)

forecast <- predict(prophet_fit, df)
```